# How do you wrap multiple UIViews in a rounded rectangle for sorting (picture attached)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In the following picture, how do you have Multi-option picker and the horizontal scroller in the same white rounded rectangle? It looks great for sorting, and I'd love to implement something like that.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a UITableView with two sections (one named "section 1" and one named "section 2").

Each section has a single row, and each row's "cell" contains an option picker inside it's "Accessory View".

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html

That option picker is not part of the system's library of controls, I don't know where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the option picker as a UIScrollView, attaching a UIPageControl to it, inside a UIView, with two UIViews (or UIImageViews) providing the transparent fading effect.  You add n-views to the scrollview, each with the same height/width.  If you want the snap, which I imagine you will, track the current page with the UIScrollViewDelegates like so:

```
-(void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    float pageWidth = scrollview.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollview.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;   
    [self scrollview:scrollview scrollToPage: page];       
}

-(void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if( decelerate == FALSE )
    {
        float pageWidth = scrollview.frame.size.width;
        int page = floor((scrollview.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

        [self scrollview:scrollview scrollToPage: page];
    }
}
```

And the scrollview:scrollToPage: method will give you the snap like so:

```
-(void) scrollview:(UIScrollView*) scrollview scrollToPage:(NSInteger) page
{
    [_myPageControl setCurrentPage:page];

    CGRect frame = scrollview.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    [scrollview scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
}
```